# How to determine the minimum quantity of EOS required to run a program on the network?

Tags: pricing

I understand that EOS coins are used to allocate bandwidth. How can I calculate the minimum amount of EOS necessary to run a particular platform/program on the EOS network?

Comment: Please mark this question as completed if you're satisfied with the answer, if not please provide more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a difficult question to answer right now as accurate resource estimates will not be available until the network is launched.

After June 2nd 2018, the EOS Resource Planner (ERP) project will be able to assist users in answering this question, you can read more about it here: https://github.com/eosnewyork/erp

Direct link: http://eosrp.io/